Three JS Mesh Edges During Morph
I have a mesh which has line segments added to it which help define its shape when rendered. i use the following code to add the lines:
// Check to see if the edges have already been calculated
if (child.children[0] instanceof THREE.LineSegments) {

  // Set the material of the lineSegments.
  let childLineSegments: any = child.children[0];
  childLineSegments.material = threeLineBasicMaterial;

}
else {

  // Remove any existing children.
  child.children = [];

  // Add the edges.
  const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(child.geometry, this.materialLineBreakAngle);
  const lines = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, threeLineBasicMaterial);
  child.add(lines);

};

I want to morph the mesh. However, I recognise that the line segments were calculated before the morph and so as the mesh morphs, the line segments remain in their original position.
I have tried to update the line segemnts by applying the following simple function which is called as the morph influence values change:
  private updateEdges(mesh: THREE.Mesh): void {

    if (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

      // Check to see if the edges have already been calculated
      if (mesh.children[0] instanceof THREE.LineSegments) {

        // Get the lineSegments.
        let childLineSegments: any = mesh.children[0];

        // Save the material.
        const lineMaterial = childLineSegments.material;

        // Remove any existing children.
        mesh.children = [];

        // Add the edges.
        const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(mesh.geometry, this.materialLineBreakAngle);
        const lines = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, lineMaterial);
        mesh.add(lines);
      };
    };
  };

After calling this function I then render the scene again. Unfortunately this didn't update the rendered line segments as I had expected, and it wasn't very performant.
where am I going wrong?
